# Aggregate on points belonging to the same dependent variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a DataFrame that holds measurement results. The independent variables are `a` and `b` and the dependent variables are `x` and `y`. Each individual result is given a integer index stored in `idx`.

| a | b | idx | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0.3 | 3 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1.2 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1.4 | 4 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 2.3 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 2.5 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 3.4 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3.6 | 6 |

Now, I would like to perform aggregations like "for each `a` and `b` pair, compute the average `x` and `y`". The expected result is:

| a | b | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0.2 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 | 1.3 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | 2.4 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 3.5 | 5 |

Currently, I am doing this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    #
    dict(a=0, b=0, idx=0, x=0.1, y=1), 
    dict(a=0, b=0, idx=1, x=0.3, y=3), 
    dict(a=0, b=1, idx=0, x=1.2, y=2), 
    dict(a=0, b=1, idx=1, x=1.4, y=4), 
    dict(a=1, b=0, idx=0, x=2.3, y=3), 
    dict(a=1, b=0, idx=1, x=2.5, y=5), 
    dict(a=1, b=1, idx=0, x=3.4, y=4), 
    dict(a=1, b=1, idx=1, x=3.6, y=6), 
    ])

df = df.set_index(['a', 'b'])
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index.names)
df = df[np.delete(df.columns.values, np.where(df.columns.values == 'idx'))]
```

But I'm wondering whether there is a built-in function that does just this..

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
print(df.drop("idx", 1).groupby(["a", "b"], as_index=False).mean())
```

Prints:

```
   a  b    x  y
0  0  0  0.2  2
1  0  1  1.3  3
2  1  0  2.4  4
3  1  1  3.5  5
```